# Limit integer size in Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

How do I specify a limit on an integer size in a Rails 4 migration? (My database is PostgreSQL.)

I have fields for `phone_number`, which should be 8 digits long. If I specify `:limit => 8`, then that is byte size rather than the length of the numbers.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think we cannot set restriction on integers when migrating instead you can check for `validates_length_of` before saving the record into db and  there you can specify length of numbers you want to allow for that particular field like this:  `validates_length_of :phone_number, :maximum => 8`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're going about this all wrong. A phone number is **not** a number at all, a phone number is a string that contains (mostly) digit characters. You don't do anything numeric – such as arithmetic – with phone numbers so they're not numbers, they're strings.

Make your `phone_number` column a string of length eight:

```
t.string :phone_number, limit: 8
```

and clean it up and validate the format in your model:

```
before_validation :clean_up_phone_number
validates :phone_number,
  format:    { with: /\A\d{8}\z/ },
  length:    { maximum: 8 },
  allow_nil: true

def clean_up_phone_number
  # Do whatever you want or need to strip out spaces, hyphens, etc. in here
end
```

Or better with PostgreSQL, don't worry about the size in the database at all and use `t.string :phone_number`. The size limit just adds pointless overhead and using a plain `varchar` rather than a `varchar(8)` makes it easier to allow for different phone number formats (area codes, extensions, international numbers, ...) later.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it with mv-core gem (https://github.com/vprokopchuk256/mv-core) right in a migration in this way (syntax is almost identical to AciveModel::Validations one):

```rb
def change
  update_table :users do |table|
    t.string :phone_number, 
             validates: { length: 8, 
                          format: /\A\d{8}\z/,
                          allow_blank: true, 
                          allow_nil: true }
  end
end
```

And then bubble up that validation to your model:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enforce_migration_validations
end
```

By default your validation will be defined as CHECK constraint for PostgreSQL. But you can change that to trigger constraint, for ex. 
See details in the documentation.